# Google In app billing 3 consuming test sku but not consuming real sku

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Today I have implemented Google in app billing version 3 following the documentation. I have a need to buy managed product multiple times hence I have written the code to consume a product every time it is purchased.

My code works fine for test skew but not working for real skew. The "PendingIntent" object  returns null every second time I try to purchase a previously purchased product Do you have any suggestions for my code?

```
IInAppBillingService mService;


ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, 
           IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
     };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
          serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
          bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

}

///////////////  on purchase button click event///////////
try {
Bundle buyIntentBundle =
 mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(),
skew, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),Integer.valueO(0));
String  purchaseToken = "inapp:"+getPackageName()+":"+skew;                         
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);  


} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}


}

}
///////////////  on purchase button click event///////////

// consuming purchase insie onActivityResult function ////



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
 if (requestCode == 1001) {           

    String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      try {
           JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
           String token=jo.getString("purchaseToken");
    // consuming here
       int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), token);


         // some database operation

              }
              catch (Exception e) {
                // alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
       }
    }


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onDestroy();
         if (mService != null) {
                unbindService(mServiceConn);
            }   
    }
```